# Doxygen latex fine-tuning?

Tags: coding-style, documentation, latex, stylesheet, doxygen

I've got 2 questions concerning the latex output of doxygen:
How can one organize the related pages (those created by \page) ? (They seem to be organized according to the title of the page)
How to specify which latex stylesheet to use ? (i've found nothing in the Doxyfile)

I would like to get rid of the paragraph numbers for the class members.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For LaTeX output, you can generate the first part of refman.tex (see LATEX_HEADER) and the style sheet included by that header (normally doxygen.sty), using:

> doxygen -w latex header.tex doxygen.sty

Answer (score 0):

In current doxygen (I use 1.8.11), you can modify the footer as well, the command by @synthesizerpatel won't work anymore. Now you have to say

```
doxygen -w latex header.tex footer.tex doxygen.sty
```

You can use the modified files by setting these variables in your `Doxyfile`

```
LATEX_HEADER           = header.tex
LATEX_FOOTER           = footer.tex
```